# How to redirect in angularjs

Tags: javascript, redirect, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This might be a trivial thing to do, but i'm a angularjs newbie.
Here is my angularjs controller code

```
    function MyCtrl1($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
  $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?");
    if (answer) {

    }
  });
}
MyCtrl1.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope'];
```

In the `next` variable i have the url to redirect on confirm OK.But how to accomplish this thing in angularjs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to manually do it. Only cancel the event if they *don't* confirm:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    if ( ! confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?") ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use either plain javascript as mentioned in other answers
or you can use $location service provided by angular like this

```
    $location.path(next)
```

OR

```
   $location.replace(next)
```

First one adds to your current path (mostly a partial)

Second one replaces current path (like google.com to yahoo.com)

Answer (score -4):

`window.location = 'myURL'`

[Here's the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)

Comment: using "window" is bad practice for Angular.js. Please always use $window instead. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$window